# passing GL_FLOAT and GL_UNSIGNED_INT into one stride

Tags: c++, opengl

I am wondering, I have the following setup:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_COORD_ATTRIB);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(TEXTURE_COORD_ATTRIB);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(COLOR_ATTRIB);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(TEXNUM_ATTRIB);

glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_COORD_ATTRIB, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, StrideSize, (void*)0);
glVertexAttribPointer(TEXTURE_COORD_ATTRIB, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, StrideSize, (void*)(VertFloatSize));
glVertexAttribPointer(COLOR_ATTRIB, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, StrideSize, (void*)(VertFloatSize + TexFloatSize));
glVertexAttribPointer(TEXNUM_ATTRIB, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, StrideSize, (void*)(VertFloatSize + TexFloatSize + ColorFloatSize));
```

while StrideSize is:

```
GLuint StrideSize = (sizeof(float) * FloatsPerVertex) + (sizeof(float) * TexCoords2D) + (sizeof(float) * ColorInfo) + (sizeof(float));
```

having in the shader

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 Coords;       
layout (location = 2) in vec2 TexCoords;
layout (location = 8) in vec4 DrawColor;
layout (location = 10) in float TexNum;
```

Everything appears to be fine as a result. However I dislike to cast TexNum, which is an unsigned int, back into uint in the shader.

But if I do:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_COORD_ATTRIB);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(TEXTURE_COORD_ATTRIB);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(COLOR_ATTRIB);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(TEXNUM_ATTRIB);

glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_COORD_ATTRIB, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, StrideSize, (void*)0);
glVertexAttribPointer(TEXTURE_COORD_ATTRIB, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, StrideSize, (void*)(VertFloatSize));
glVertexAttribPointer(COLOR_ATTRIB, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, StrideSize, (void*)(VertFloatSize + TexFloatSize));
glVertexAttribIPointer(TEXNUM_ATTRIB, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, StrideSize, (void*)(VertFloatSize + TexFloatSize + ColorFloatSize));
```

while StrideSize is:

```
GLuint StrideSize = (sizeof(float) * FloatsPerVertex) + (sizeof(float) * TexCoords2D) + (sizeof(float) * ColorInfo) + (sizeof(GLuint));
```

having in the shader

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 Coords;       
layout (location = 2) in vec2 TexCoords;
layout (location = 8) in vec4 DrawColor;
layout (location = 10) in uint TexNum;
```

the value doesn't seem to be passed correctly. I know that glVertexAttribPointer always converts into float and that glVertexAttribIPointer is to be used instead. 
What did I miss? Is it not allowed to pass 2 different datatypes in one stride? Or do I have to buffer it separately? 
I found a couple of almost similar questions, but none asking this specifically, but I also didn't find any indication somewhere why this shouldn't work.
Passing TexNum as uniform also works out correctly, but is not really handy if I want to batch my drawcalls.

Forgive me if I am just blind again :)

Comment: Could you please show how you defined your data in the second case?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention that in case of GL_UNSIGNED_INT for TexNum, you actually have ints in memory instead of floats.

So, do you convert your TexNum to int?

(you can pass whatever datatypes you want in one stride, it must work)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, to be honest :) - my TexNum is an int in the first place, that's why I wanted to avoid the conversion into float at all. However, passing it as float seems to make way less hassle on the c++ side, so perhaps it makes little sense at all. Still I was curious to know if this is actually working.

Comment: @Gnampf: in the first snippet, you've written `glVertexAttribPointer(TEXNUM_ATTRIB, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, ...)`, so `TexNum` has to be float in memory. Then, you write `glVertexAttribIPointer(TEXNUM_ATTRIB, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, ...)`, where `TexNum` has to be int in memory. That's why I asked whether you converted your `TexNum` data from float to int.